# Python scipy.optimize.f_min_l_bfgs_b algorithm: how to have extra outputs?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, function-attributes

I am using L-BFGS-B optimizer from Scipy package. Here is the  [documentation.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html)

My code has the following structure. obj_func is the objective function that is used to minimize "a". In order to do so, obj_func should only return "a".

Question: Is there a way to obtain "b" and "c" from obj_func?

Currently I am using function attribute. But I am not sure this is the preferred way.

```
def obj_func(x, *args)
    a, b, c = compute(x) # compute is where major computation happens
    # I want to access b and c from outside the function
    obj_func.result = [b,c] # use function attribute
    return a

result = optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b(obj_func, x0, bounds=bounds, args=args)
b, c = obj_func.result
```

Comment: *"Currently I am using function attribute."*  Are you sure that the last call to `obj_func` performed by `fmin_l_bfgs` is with the optimal `x`?

Comment: That is a good point. Is there a way to check that?

Comment: You could save `a`, `b` and `c`, and only reassign the values to the attribute if the old `a` is larger than the new `a`.  You could also save `x`, and verify at the end that the saved `x` is the same as the `x` that is returned by `fmin_l_bfgs`.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, is it a good practice to use the attribute to save these items? Are these the only way?

Comment: An alternative would be to pass in a dictionary as an additional argument in `args`, and save the auxiliary variables in the dictionary instead of in an attribute of the function.

Comment: Oh, I see. So I can send the reference of dictionary object as a function argument, and mutate the dictionary inside the function. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Have you tried `_, b, c = compute(result.x)`, i. e. just evaluating part of the objective again for the optimal value?